# Socket.io game. How to add new character

Tags: node.js, socket.io, character

I was writinig a game using Socket.io and I have problem, when server create new img (new character) i can only see it on one computer.. 
I wanna in this case, for every connected computer see the same amount of images
Better if you look on this
Thanks for every help

**SERVER:**

```
    var handler = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var port =  3250;

app.listen(port);
var postacie = [];
var ile=0;

// socket.io
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    postacie[ile]=createChar();
    ile++;
    io.sockets.emit("tworz", postacie);


    socket.on("disconnect", function()
    {
        postacie.splice(0, 1);
        io.sockets.emit("tworz", postacie);
    })

});


function createChar()
{
    var postac = {
        src: "http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1416/2st.gif",
        id: "character"
    }
    return postac;
}
```

**CLIENT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Real tie game</title>
        <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3250');

                socket.on("tworz", function(data)
                {
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                     var element = document.createElement('img'); 
                    element.src = data[i].src;
                    element.id = data[i].id;

                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
                    body.appendChild(element); 
                    };

                })

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

AND IT LOOK LIKE THIS 
http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/4793/q10w.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit. Hope it helps you move in correct direction:

The main idea is to use 3 basic messages:

1. join -- when new client connects the server send info about newbie to all other clients;
2. list -- when new client connects the server send him the list of already connected clients;
3. leave -- when someone disconnected the server send id of disconnected client

Server:

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var port =  3250;

app.listen(port);
var postacie = [];
var idGenerator = 0;

// socket.io
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var pId = idGenerator++;
    socket.emit("list", postacie);

    var postac = createChar(pId);
    postacie.push(postac);
    io.sockets.emit("join", postac);

    socket.on("disconnect", function()
    {
        var sId = "character" + pId;
        for (var i = 0,n=postacie.length; i < n; ++i) {
            var postac = postacie[i];
            if (postac.id == sId) {
                io.sockets.emit("leave", {id:postac.id});
                postacie.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

});


function createChar(id)
{
    var postac = {
        src: "http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1416/2st.gif",
        id: "character" + id
    };
    return postac;
}
```

Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Real tie game</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3250');

                socket.on("join", function(data)
                {
                    var element = document.createElement('img');
                    element.src = data.src;
                    element.id = data.id;

                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                    body.appendChild(element);

                });
                socket.on("list", function(data)
                {
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      var element = document.createElement('img');
                      element.src = data[i].src;
                      element.id = data[i].id;

                      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                      body.appendChild(element);
                    };

                });
                socket.on("leave", function(data)
                {
                    var element = document.getElementById(data.id);
                    if (element)
                        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```